# SLD- double line (offset) shows only one of two lines in legend

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I've made a double line from a single line feature using the following code:

```
  <NamedLayer>
<Name>Name1</Name>
<UserStyle>
  <Title>Title1</Title>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Title>Title2</Title>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ffff00</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">5 2</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ff6600</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">5 2</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>4</PerpendicularOffset>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

This shows up fine in my mapviewer.  However, in the legend I can only see the first line along with the "Title1".

Is there a way to make the legend show both the first line and the offset-line along with "title1" by editing the sld code?